# Filter massive linux log files

Tags: python, filter

I have the user input into a list the items it would like to filter out.  From there it filters using:

```
while knownIssuesCounter != len(newLogFile):
    for line in knownIssues:
        if line in newLogFile[knownIssuesCounter]:
            if line not in issuesFound:
                issuesFoundCounter[line]=1
                issuesFound.append(line)
                issuesFound.append(knownIssues[line])
            else:
                issuesFoundCounter[line]=issuesFoundCounter[line] + 1
    knownIssuesCounter +=1
```

I'm running into hundred meg log files and it is taking FOREVER.....
Is there a better way to be doing this with Python?

Comment: Why aren't you using the inbuilt Linux commands? Something with a bit of grep, awk and wc magic?

Comment: With my job we work on MANY many linux logs all of this nature.  Was hoping to be able to filter out certain groups of information depending on the nature of the issue and then pass the filtered logs on to the lower teams who aren't as good with grep and such.

Comment: As a side note, iterating with explicit counters like this makes your code harder to read. Why not just `for newLogLine in newLogFile:` for the outer loop?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `issuesFound` from a list to set:

```
issuesFound = set()
```

and use `add` instead of `append`:

```
issuesFound.add(line)
```

Comment: I think he wants the `issuesFound` list (which contains both `line` and `knownIssues[line]`, and the order may be important), but he _also_ wants a `set` to do the quick "check if already seen".

Answer (score 0):

A big part of the reason your code is so slow is that `if line not in issuesFound:`. This requires a linear search through a huge list.

You can fix that by adding a `set` of seen issues (which is effectively free to search). That reduces your time from O(NM) to O(N).

But really, you can make this even simpler by removing the `if` entirely.

First, you can generate the `issuesFound` list after the fact from the keys of `issuesFoundCounter`. For each line in `issuesFoundCounter`, you want that line, and then its `knownIssues[line]`. So:

```
issuesFound = list(flatten((line, knownIssues[line]) for line in issuesFoundCounter))
```

(I'm using the `flatten` recipe from the `itertools` docs. You can copy that into your code, or you can just write this with `itertools.chain.from_iterable` instead of `flatten`.)

And that means you can just search `if line not in issuesFoundCounter:` instead of `in issuesFound:`, which is already a `dict` (and therefore effectively free to search). But if you just use `setdefault`—or, even simpler, use a `defaultdict` or a `Counter` instead of a `dict`—you can make that automatic.

So, if `issuesFoundCounter` is a `Counter`, the whole thing reduces to this:

```
for newLogLine in newLogFile:
    for line in knownIssues:
        if line in newLogLine:
            issuesFoundCounter[line] += 1
```

And you can turn that into a generator expression, eliminating the slow-ish explicit looping in Python with faster looping inside the interpreter guts. This is only going to be, say, a fixed 5:1 speedup, as opposed to the linear-to-constant speedup from the first half, but it's still worth considering:

```
issuesFoundCounter = collections.Counter(line 
                                         for newLogLine in newLogFile
                                         for line in knownIssues
                                         if line in newLogLine)
```

The only problem with this is that the `issuesFound` list is now in arbitrary order, instead of in the order that the issues are found. If that's important, just use an `OrderedCounter` instead of a `Counter`. There's a simple recipe in the `collections` docs, but for your case, it can be as simple as:

```
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass
```

Comment: Any problem that can be solved entirely with the empty space between a comment and a signature is a good problem. :)